# How to install open jdk 12 on debian?

Tags: debian, openjdk

I tried to install openjdk 12 using `sudo apt install openjdk-12-jdk`,
but throughout installation process, it changed to the Oracle jdk 12 package.

Comment: https://superuser.com/help/on-topic - please use English. If you are unsure regarding words or wording, then you might try to use Google Translate as an aid in the process.

Comment: It can be installed on debian bullseye (debian 11).

Answer (score 1):

I assume you are running Debian `stable` (Buster) or an older release. OpenJDK 12 did not make it into Buster, but is [available in `testing`](https://packages.debian.org/search?keywords=openjdk-12-jdk&searchon=names&suite=all&section=all).
To install it, you have to add the following lines to your `/etc/apt/sources.list` file:

```
deb http://httpredir.debian.org/debian/ testing main non-free contrib
deb-src http://httpredir.debian.org/debian/ testing main non-free contrib
deb http://security.debian.org/ testing-security/updates main contrib non-free
deb-src http://security.debian.org/ testing-security/updates main contrib non-free
```

You probably do not want to upgrade other packages to `testing`. Therefore create a new file `/etc/apt/preferences.d/testing` containing:

```
Package: *
Pin: release a=testing
Pin-Priority: 5
```

Now you should be able to install the package:

```
sudo apt update; apt install -t testing openjdk-12-jdk
```

**Warning:** Installing packages from different Debian releases is **not [adviced](https://www.debian.org/doc/manuals/debian-reference/ch02.en.html#_packages_from_mixed_source_of_archives)** and may break your system. However, in most cases it works flawlessly.